# Devise login form with form_inline in the navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, header, navbar

I am trying to  make a  Devise login form as form_inline in my navbar.

At this point a have made it like this:
Link to picture of the navbar it look like a this point: http://postimg.org/image/i3ka5fsur/
it has the code:

```
<li><%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password"  %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %>
      <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
    <% end %></li>
```

I'm just not quite happy with it's look at this point, I more want it like the form_inline:
Link to picture of the navbar I want it to look like: http://postimg.org/image/7590n949f/

the form_inline code is:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Hope some of you can help me, i'm new a programmering and don't have a lot of experience with programmering.

Comment: are you using twitter bootstrap.?

Comment: Yeah, bootstrap ~ 2.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with twitter bootstrap3

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user), html: { class: "navbar-form navbar-right form-inline" }) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", class: "form-control" %> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", class: "form-control"  %>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Login', class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

with twitter bootstrap2

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user), html: { class: "navbar-form pull-right form-inline" }) do |f| %>   
        <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", class: "input-small" %> 
        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", class: "input-small"  %>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </label>
        <%= f.submit 'Login', class: "btn" %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the css that describes form_inline class and input-small class e.t.c
Then in your code you should assign classes to your elements like below

```
<li><%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)), :class => "form-inline" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :class => "input-small" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => "input-small"  %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" %><%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Login', :class => "btn" %>
<% end %></li>
```

Comment: thanks, but when i do it, it shows an error with the :class => "form-inline". So when i delete :class => "form-inline" from the script

Comment: <li><%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :class => "input-small" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => "input-small"  %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" %><%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Login', :class => "btn" %>
    <% end %></li>

Comment: than it's gonna look like: http://postimg.org/image/y17grg0vj/

I like the outcome of the script now, but do you know how to get it on a straight line on the navbar?

Comment: Indeed,my mistake! The correct first line of the code is  form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user), html: { class: "navbar-form navbar-right form-inline" }). Sorry for that